# Is this general nested radical for $\pi$ true?

Tags: trigonometry, radicals, pi, nested-radicals, golden-ratio

We have,

**I.** [Liu Hui](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Approximations_of_%CF%80#Other_classical_formulae) (c. 300 AD)
$$\pi \approx 3\cdot2^{\color{red}8}\times \underbrace{\sqrt{2 - \sqrt{2 + \sqrt{2 + \sqrt{2 + \sqrt{2 + \sqrt{2 + \sqrt{2 + \sqrt{2 + \sqrt{2+\sqrt{\color{blue}1}}}}}}}}}}}_{\color{red}{10}\text{ square roots}}$$

**II.** [Viete](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vi%C3%A8te%27s_formula#Related_formulas) (c. 1590 AD)

$$\pi = \lim_{k\to\infty} 4\cdot2^{\color{red}{k}}\times \underbrace{\sqrt{2-\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2+\cdots+\sqrt{\color{blue}2}}}}}}}}}_{\color{red}{k+2}\text{ square roots}}$$

**III.** (yours truly)

$$\pi \approx 6\cdot2^{\color{red}8}\times \underbrace{\sqrt{2 - \sqrt{2 + \sqrt{2 + \sqrt{2 + \sqrt{2 + \sqrt{2 + \sqrt{2 + \sqrt{2 + \sqrt{2+\sqrt{\color{blue}3}}}}}}}}}}}_{\color{red}{10}\text{ square roots}}$$

For the blue numbers, I tried $\sqrt{5}$, $\sqrt{6}$, and other $\sqrt{n}$, nothing worked, until I remembered $\sqrt{2}$ and $\sqrt{3}$ has a *trigonometric* context.

---

**Question:** Given,

$$\color{blue}{\beta}=4\cos^2\left(\frac{\pi}{\color{brown}{\alpha}}\right)$$

then is it true that,

$$\pi = \lim_{k\to\infty} \color{brown}{\alpha}\cdot2^{\color{red}{k}}\times \underbrace{\sqrt{2-\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2+\cdots+\sqrt{\color{blue}\beta}}}}}}}}}_{\color{red}{k+2}\text{ square roots}}$$

So the first three are simply the cases $\alpha = 3,4,6$, though if the general form is true, then one can use other positive integers.

**P.S.** For example, note that if $\alpha = 5$, then we relate $\pi$ to our old friend the *golden ratio* $\phi$,

$$\pi = \lim_{k\to\infty} \color{brown}{5}\cdot2^{\color{red}{k}}\times \underbrace{\sqrt{2-\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2+\cdots+\sqrt{\color{blue}{\phi^2}}}}}}}}}}_{\color{red}{k+2}\text{ square roots}}$$

Comment: Though I don't have time to write a full answer right now, I can tell you that if this identity is true, then it can almost certainly be obtained by repeatedly applying the cosine half-angle formula, followed by the sin half-angle formula, and noting that: $$\pi=\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}x\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{x}\right)$$

Comment: @C-RAM Feel free to answer it when you have time. We will wait.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Firstly, we define the recursive sequence
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
A_{k+1}&=\sqrt{2+A_k}\\
A_0&=\sqrt{\beta}=2\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{\alpha}\right)\\
\end{split}
\end{equation}
and let $B_k=\sqrt{2-A_k}$. Your claim is that
$$\pi=\lim_{k\rightarrow\infty}2^k\alpha B_k$$
To prove this claim, we shall first show by induction that $A_k$ admits the simple closed form
$$A_k=2\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{2^k\alpha}\right)$$
By definition, the above equality is satisfied for $k=0$. Suppose that the above formula is true for $k$, then by the cos half-angle formula $2\cos(x/2)=\sqrt{2+2\cos(x)}$, we have that
$$A_{k+1}=\sqrt{2+A_k}=\sqrt{2+2\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{2^k\alpha}\right)}=2\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{2^{k+1}\alpha}\right)$$
and therefore, by induction $A_k=2\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{2^k\alpha}\right)$ for all $k\geq 0$. Now, applying the sin half-angle formula $2\sin(x/2)=\sqrt{2-2\cos(x)}$ gives us that
$$B_k=\sqrt{2-A_k}=\sqrt{2-2\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{2^k\alpha}\right)}=2\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{2^{k+1}\alpha}\right)$$
Finally, applying the fact that $\pi=\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{\sin(\pi x)}{x}$, we have that
$$\lim_{k\rightarrow\infty}2^k\alpha B_k=\lim_{k\rightarrow\infty}2^{k+1}\alpha\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{2^{k+1}\alpha}\right)=\pi$$
as desired.

Comment: As a note: Most identities involving similar nested radicals of $2$ can be evaluated using the same methods. This is where identities like [Viéte's formula](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vi%C3%A8te%27s_formula) come from. I too have played around and created a few identities of this sort in the past; they certainly make for odd looking formulas. : )

Comment: When I first found $(1), (2), (3)$, I naturally wondered what other "kernel" ($\sqrt1, \sqrt2,\sqrt3$, respectively) could be used. It was quite satisfying to find the general form. :)